# Prove the Zero divisor of Z[2]

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

$K$ is a  field and $A=K[\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z]$ is a group algebra from $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ to $K$.
How can I prove that there is a zero divisor in $A$?
Shall I find the basis first?

Comment: What's the value of $x^2$?

Comment: @Quimey $x^2$=1

Answer (score 0):

Take $g \in \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ to be $g=(1,0)$. Then, $g^2=1$, so in the group algebra $g^2-1=0$, which is $(g+1)(g-1)=0$. Thus, $g+1$ and $g-1$ are zero divisors.

Comment: And the benefit to the OP from somebody else doing their exercise for them is what exactly?

Comment: @AlexB. It depends on the OP. He may work out this example and realize that it is a general phenomenon for elements $g$ of finite order, or at least of order two. He may just take the example for granted. The question asked for a zero divisor, which I seem to have provided, and not for any other benefit.

If you think this doesn't answer the question, or the answer is incorrect, then, please, indicate why you think so. Otherwise, your comment appears nonconstructive to me.

Comment: Actually, the question asked "how can I find...", it did not ask "please find for me...". That is why I think this that does not answer the question. In general, when lecturers set exercises for students, they do that on the assumption that the student already has all the knowledge they need to do the exercise, and should not need somebody else to give them the solution.

Comment: @AlexB. I don't get your point. In my opinion, I have shown "how to find" a zero divisor in this particular case. Whether this is an exercise from some lectures or not, and what exact assumptions did exist in the potential lecturer's mind, is irrelevant, at least because it is not in any way mentioned in the question. If you have a better answer to the question, please, provide one.

Comment: In my opinion, a better answer to the question would have been one that would have resulted in the OP solving the exercise themselves, rather than being given the solution. This was tried in the comments before you supplied the full solution. The problem with people rushing to just give out the solution is that it would be pointless for me to now follow your suggestion and provide a "better" answer. That's the thing with exercises: once one "destroys" an exercise or a riddle by looking up or being told the solution, one cannot undestroy it. In any case, I have said ...

Comment: ... my piece, and if you don't get my point, then unfortunately we will have to leave it at that.